# Icons on top status/menu bar in gnome not following theme

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, icons, icon-themes

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I added an icon theme and activated it using Unity Tweaks.  All icons everywhere have changed to my new theme, but the top bar hasn't changed.  All icons are still from the original Humanity pack and when a window is maximised, it's "minimise", "maximise" and "close" icons in the top status/menu bar are the plain ones from the Humanity theme.

Here's the screenshot of what a themed window looks like (left corner only):

[image]

And here's the screenshot of what the maximised (in top status/menu bar at the top) window looks like:

[image]

The rest of the icons on the top bar in the right hand side are also remaining in the original theme and are not changing.  How can I force the icons to update in the top bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.  Apparently, due to some internal conflicts, Unity was running in 2D mode.  It took some tinkering with config files and installing some additional packages to get it to run in 3D with compiz - and now all the icons are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Log out and then back in.

The new theme hasn't been loaded into Unity. And Unity manages windows borders.

About `The rest of the icons on the top bar in the right hand side` they are not supplied by the theme you are using.

Comment: I tried logging out and in and rebooting the machine - this does not help.  The rest of the icons _are_ supplied by the theme, as I can navigate into the theme and see the icons there.

Comment: @AleksG the theme are you using is specifially designed for Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Yes, it is.  This same theme is working fine on another machine with the same ubuntu 12.04.